# Support for border radius using CSS jQuery and/or other solutions

Tags: css

I am using code like this to set border-radius:

```
#leftwrap    { background:#FDFDFD; position:fixed; width:10px; top:90px; bottom:35px; left:230px;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa; border-left: 1px solid #aaa; border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;  
}
```

Works great but of course not for versions of IE.

I'm looking into adding IE support and would appreciate suggestions as to which method people are using. High up on my list would be support using a jQuery plug in. However I would also like to look into other alternatives but NO alternative that requires images.

Thanks,

Judy

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, I tend to just let the IE users have square corners, but I have read that the http://www.curvycorners.net/ Javascript library works quite well.

I don't believe it uses images either.